# Donate to multiple funds on website

Tags: forms, paypal, donations

I work for a non-profit charity, and we would like to set up forms on our website so that visitors can donate to multiple funds at once, with an amount of their choosing.

I've created a "donate" button from PayPal, and I've discovered how to create an "amount" field for the user to fill in. However, it appears to only work for one fund, even if I try to create multiple "amount" forms. We would like to have 4-6 fillable "amount" items, so that a user could donate to multiple funds at the same time. Once they have filled in the box fields, we want the "donate" button to redirect them to PayPal to complete the order.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this, but based on the information you've provided I would use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) and do a [parallel payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECParallelPaymens/).

You could get this done very easily using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It has samples and templates setup for each of the Express Checkout calls, which include:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/templates/SetExpressCheckout.php)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/templates/GetExpressCheckoutDetails.php)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/templates/DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php)